# 什么都没有 和 没有什么 difference

Tags: translation, grammar, meaning

Good day everyone, pls help me to confirm that there are quite a difference between these two sentences like
我跟那件事一点关系也没有。

我跟那件事没有什么关系。
Which supposed to be translated as “I have nothing to do with that”.

The same question with these two sentences:

我什么城市也不想去 and 我哪个城市也不想去。
I don't want to go to any city.

Which one is correct.
Thx in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your 2nd question about the city,
both `我什么城市也不想去` and `我哪个城市也不想去` are correct way of expressing `I don't want to go to any city.`

`我哪个城市也不想去` seems more colloquial and native-speaker expression to me. `我什么城市也不想去` could subtly indicate he/she prefers stay in suburban/rural areas vs. `我哪个城市也不想去` indicates I prefer to stay as-is.

Comment: Thx a lot for your explanation!!!

Answer (score 2):

The first (我跟那件事一点关系也没有) is supposed to translate into “I have nothing to do with that.”
The second one (我跟那件事没有什么关系) should be translated into "I don't have much to do with that."

Comment: Yes, that’s what I was thinking, just need to reconfirm that, and about the sentence about the city, thx a lot!!!